# how to set state data subtracting from 100 and data itself inside a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How will pass the data in this format [25, 75] where second element data is coming from subtracting first Element from 100 ? Suggest a solution.
here data is coming from json  { pharma1 : "25"}

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
function pharmacyData(data){
   const data1 = [];
   const one = data
   const two = 100 - parse Float(data);
   data1.push(one);
   data1.push(two);
   setData(data1);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JSON is in `pharmaData` and of the form `{ pharma1: "25" }` you can do this to parse and populate the array:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
function pharmacyData(pharamaData){
   let val = parseFloat(pharmaData.pharma1)
   let final = [val, 100 - val]
   setData(final);
}
```